Matter.JS Scaling textures automatically + sprites not on body
I am making a game where every time you click, a fruit falls down from the mouse coordinates. The game was working when I was working with plain colours, so then I decided to add textures. However, I encountered two issues.

I have to manually add in xScale and yScale, which isn't good since there are many different fruits and sizes and I don't want to manually tune it for all of them. I tried to get the size of the body and divide it by the image size. My code is below:

// getting the size of the fruit by the type of fruit it is
radius = fruit_kinds.indexOf(kind)*6+10

// making the fruit, note that I already defined mouse_x before
fruit = Bodies.circle(mouse_x, 120, radius, { isStatic: false })

// getting the image
const path = '../static/assets/cherry.png';
const image = new Image();
image.src = path;

// getting the scales (this might not work). 
// Note that 2*radius = diameter = width of fruit
xscale = 2*radius/(image.width)
yscale = 2*radius/(image.height)

// adding it to the body parameters
fruit['render']['sprite']['texture'] = path
fruit['render']['sprite']['xScale'] = xscale
fruit['render']['sprite']['yScale'] = yscale

When I ran this code, the sprite became so small that I could barely see it. I suspect that the radius isn't in the same units as the image size I got? But I am not sure. Help would be appreciated!

The sprite I added was not appearing directly on the body. There seems to be some offset. I thought that the offset was due to xOffset and yOffset, so I made them zero.

fruit['render']['sprite']['xOffset'] = 0
fruit['render']['sprite']['yOffset'] = 0

However, when I tried this, the fruit disappeared.
I have checked many other StackOverflow posts, however none of these can help with my problem.

Sprite image not appearing on matter.js The image is appearing, just not the right size and not the right place.
How to apply sprite textures to matter.js bodies Again, the image is appearing for me. Also, I am not using a canvas, not even a div element. Would that be a bad thing?
Matter.Js scaling a sprite (related to other variables) That question regards expression xScale in terms of other variables, but I want to automatically find xScale such that it covers the whole body almost perfectly.

Could somebody please help? Thank you in advance :D

You need to wait until the image is loaded before width and height properties are defined.

@ggorlen, thank you, but it still doesn't work. I printed out the height and width, and I got the same thing no matter whether I waited for it to load or not.

Can you share a [mcve] please? See the linked post for how to create runnable Matter.js Stack Snippets. I'd load the image, then create the body and scale accordingly, rather then creating the body, loading the image, then scaling the body after the fact.

Why would the order matter in this case?

Because you don't know what the image size can't read width/height properties until it's loaded. If you print image.width it'll be undefined, unless maybe it's a second run and the image is cached, but that won't be the case for your users on first load. Loading happens asynchronously. Did you try using the code in my linked post and providing a [mcve] as requested? I don't see any [edit]s have been applied here, so the post is still not fit for answering.
